# event.stopPropogation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

I know `event.stopPropogation()` is used to stop event bubbling i.e. it will stop firing parent events but in my this code it's not working. Can you please check this:

```
<div onClick="diva();">
div
<p onClick="pa();">
ppp
<a onClick="aa();">
  hello
</a>
</p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

function diva(){
alert('div')
}

function pa(){
alert('p')
}

function aa(event){
    event.stopPropogation();
    alert('a')

}
</script>
```

It's alerting `P` and `Div` while it should just alert `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Your event is undefined .Pass event as follows :

```
<a onclick="aa(event);">
```

```js
function diva(){
console.log('div')
}

function pa(){
console.log('p')
}

function aa(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('a')

}
```

```html
<div onclick="diva();">
div
<p onclick="pa();">
p
<a onclick="aa(event);">
  hello
</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Added the code run the code snippet click on hello and check the console only "a" is console logged.

Comment: yeah working now thanks and you know there was one more error of spell error it was stopPropagation and I was using stopPropogation huh